# How to select multi value from a table using stored procedures

Tags: sql-server

I have an app for time and attendance made with c# and SQL Server 2005. In SQL I created a stored procedure with 3 parameters.

The event table is something like this:

```
UnitTS          RdrName          RdrIn_Out    CrdName

201401030759    Office1             B        Mike             
201401030819    Office2             B        Alex           
201401030944    Office2             B        Alex             
201401030947    Office2             B        Tomy             
201401030955    Office3             B        John           
201401030955    Office3             A        John          
201401031015    Office1             B        Alex                   
201401031034    Office1             A        Alex                   
201401031457    Office1             B        Alex                
201401031626    Office1             A        Alex                 
201401031649    Office2             B        Janina                 
201401031727    Office2             B        Janina
```

After executing the stored procedure I get the following result:

```
CrdName|RdrName  | Date  | In_Time | Out_Time | Duration

Alex    Office 1  03-01-2014 09:35   09:41       360
Alex    Office 1  03-01-2014 unknown 09:41        0
Alex    Office 1  03-01-2014 14:58   14:59       60
Alex    Office 1  03-01-2014 unknown 14:59        0
```

Here is the query

```
   @Emp nvarchar(50),
   @Start_Date nvarchar(50),
   @End_Date nvarchar(50)
as
   with Ordered as 
   ( select 
       convert(varchar(15), cast(Substring(unitts,1,8) as DATE), 105 ) as Data, 
       Substring(UnitTS,9,2)+':'+ Substring(UnitTS,11,2) as EventTime,
           case when RdrHead = 'A' THEN 'OUT' ELSE 'IN 'END as Reader,
           [RdrName],
           [CrdName],
           rn = row_number() over (order by RdrName)
    from 
        Time.dbo.History 
    where 
        (UnitNr = '3' and RdrNr IN ('0','2','3') OR UnitNr = '4' and RdrNr IN('1','6')) 
        and Type = 'A' 
        and Substring(unitts, 1, 8) >= @Start_Date 
        and Substring(unitts, 1, 8) <= @End_Date and (CrdName in (@emp) or @emp= 'all')
)
select
    o_out.CrdName,
    o_out.RdrName,
    o_out.Data,
    case when o_in.EventTime is null then 'unknown' else o_in.EventTime end In_Time,
    [Out_Time] = o_out.EventTime ,
    case when cast(datediff (s,o_in.EventTime ,o_out.EventTime) AS int) is null then '0' ELSE cast(datediff (S,o_in.EventTime ,o_out.EventTime) as int) END Duration
from Ordered o_out
 left join Ordered o_in
   on o_in.rn = o_out.rn - 1
  and o_in.Reader ='in'
where o_out.Reader= 'out'
```

The code is ok if I want to select one `CrdName`. The problem is when I want to select all `CrdName`. The result is incorrect. I tried to order data by `CrdName` but no result.

I think, I need to order somehow the Events table by UnitTS,RdrName and CrdName

Is there any solution ? Thank you

Comment: in first CTE looks like you are filtering results on `@emp` parameter unless `@emp = 'all'` . So what happens when you pass `@emp = 'all'`?

Comment: i have 2 possible selections, 1 selection for one emp and the second is for all emp. If the parameter @emp have value 'all' then select all events for all cardname

Comment: you need to be more clear on what exactly is the problem when returning all. if you simply want to order your results why not add `Order By` clause at the end of your statement.

Comment: if i use order in  with Ordered as i have the next error The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.
If i use order as after i calculate the rows it not helping me

Comment: I'm still unsure what exactly that you are asking. Can you include what result you are expecting when passing **all** value? Additionally you need to explain what you want to do with "Order by"

Comment: i found the problem.  replace rn = row_number() over (order by RdrName) with rn = row_number() over (order by CrdName, Unitts) Thank you for your time